# Insercion de campos de cantidad variables en base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net

tenía una duda. 
Quiero hacer un programa genérico de insercción de Temperaturas con fecha y hora. Solo que las temperaturas dependiendo de la instalación pueden variar. Y Claro quisiera hacer un código entendible y no basado en que si en una instalación hay 7 campos de temperatura y en otro 13, tenga que manchar el código escribiendo más campos en esta línea de consulta. Tenéis alguna solución más optima. Que realizar esta insercción tal como yo la hago?

Ejemplo de insercción de la fecha/hora con 7 temperaturas

```
 querystring = "insert into Temperaturas (FechaHora,TempCam1,TempCam2,TempCam3,TempCamFrescos,TempMuelle,TempSalaElab,TempTunel) values(convert(datetime,'" & fechas & "', 103)," & valorTemperatura(0).LeerEntero &
                "," & valorTemperatura(1).LeerEntero & "," & valorTemperatura(2).LeerEntero & "," & valorTemperatura(3).LeerEntero &
                "," & valorTemperatura(4).LeerEntero & "," & valorTemperatura(5).LeerEntero & "," & valorTemperatura(6).LeerEntero & ")"
```

Muchas gracias, por haber leído este mensaje. Espero su pronta respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en tu modelo de datos....

Como decis que tu modelo de toma de temperatura es variable, no podes hacer una base de datos que tenga todos los posibles campos que se requieren.. Entonces necesitas un modelo donde el usuario pueda generar tantos campos de temperatura como desee, y eso se refleje en tu base de datos.

El codigo te lo dejo a vos, pero tu modelo de datos debe tener la forma:

```
Tipo_Temperatura
Id numerico
Descripcion texto

Temperatura
Id numerico
Tipo numerico (apunta a tipo_temperatura)
fecha
valor numerico
```

Luego de eso, tu Interfaz debe representar tantos campos en la pantalla como tipos de temperatura halla.

Y luego, tu insert debe ser capaz de mandar tantos registros como tipos halla.

Comment: Realmente no tengo problemas en añadir o desañadir a mano los campos en la base de datos. Tengo más problemas en el código de vb.net. En plan, no se que manera utilizar para que si tengo x campos me inserte x valores. Llevo poco con VB.net por eso que ando un poco perdido.

Comment: Pero lo que estas haciendo no es incorrecto.. o sea, si tenes que mandar 20 campos que el usuario inserto en una pantalla, tenes que hacerlo asi.. tenes que pasar cada dato a la db de alguna forma...@Samus200

Comment: Incorrecto no digo que sea, me refería a sí hay alguna forma más limpia de hacer esto. porque si por ejemplo fuesen 50 campos el insert me quedaría muy estratosférico. Aunque no creo que nunca llegue a extremos tan locos para añadir unas cuantas temperaturas XD

Comment: Muchas gracias a todo esto, por tus respuestas ;)

Comment: Es asi.. si tenes 50 campos.. son 50 concatenaciones.. o mejor, serian 50 parametros si usaras un command. En el caso que mostras, como tenes un array de controle, podrias usar un for.. pero en otros casos, tenes que ir campo por campo, o recorrer un form si usaras wpf.. pero la mejor forma y mas limpia siempre es hacerlo asi. @Samus200

Comment: Lo que me doy cuenta, es que mi respuesta no te sirve para nada a tu duda.. pense que hablabas de un programa que fuera para muchos usuarios con requerimientos distintos... @Samus200

Comment: Aun así agradezco la intención. Seguiré buscando y alguna solución más óptima encontraré en el camino :).

Comment: Es que no hay... no se que estas buscando.. si tenes 40 campos en la pantalla, podes hacer magia (en wpf recorrer el form buscando esos campos, en tu caso usar un forpara armar el string).. pero siempre, tenes que mover los datos de la pantalla a la base de datos, campo por campo... tal vez si decis cual es la idea que se te ocurre, te pueda orientar mejor :) @Samus200